# Why do I have to add a blank __init__.py file to import from subdirectories

Tags: python

I can import from subdirectories with a blank `__init__.py` file. That works fine. I think that init file in python works like an index file. But I really don't understand why the `__init__.py` file is blank to import. How do `__init__.py` file and importing really work?

What have to be `__init__.py` files content?

Comment: Because it's required by Python specification?

Answer (score 3):

The `__init__.py` has two main functions:

- **Marking packages**: It marks a directory as a Python *package*, and the inner `.py` files as Python *modules*.
- **Initialization code**: As its name suggests, any code inside the `__init__.py` is automatically executed when the package is imported. This is the right place to run initialization code required for a certain package; however, it's perfectly OK to leave the `__init__.py` file empty.

Comment: Is this not a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Adam! That clered question marks in my mind.

Comment: @alpi Sure. If it's the right answer, don't forget to mark it as accepted so that other users won't spend time on it.

Comment: @PeterWood Not as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

The subdirectory that you are importing from is a *package* if it has an `__init__.py` file in it.  You don't need to use packages, you can just add the subdirectory to the `sys.path` list.  However they are a neat way of keeping related modules together and are generally encouraged.

The `__init__.py` file has a similar purpose to the `__init__` in a class, it initialises the package.  This enables attributes to be given to the *package*, and `__all__` is an example (list of exported names for `import *`).

There is sometimes no initialisation required, so it can be empty.  A good place to look for examples is in the standard library subdirectories of the `Lib` directory.  There you will find huge `__init__.py` files, and others that are empty.

Whether this is mandatory or not depends on the Python version.  From Python 3.3 the `__init__.py` is not mandatory, and such packages are called *Namespace Packages*, see [PEP0420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/).  This means that a package can span directories, but there is a price to pay.  There can be no `__init__.py` initialisation code and you don't get a `__file__` attribute for the package.  So unless you specifically need to span directories it is probably better to stick with regular packages.