# Importing in python packages compared to normal scripts

Tags: python, pip

I've written a small python code that parses data from a file and then uses Selenium to input the data into a website, and I am trying to bundle it with a script.

I was already able to bundle it into a pip package and upload it, but when trying to run it I get `ImportError: No module named '<name>'` for modules on the same directory.

My structure is pretty simply

```
chessil_tourney_inserter/
    setup.py
    chessil_tourney_inserter/
        __init__.py (empty)
        chessil_tourney_inserter.py
        swiss98_text_parser.py
        command_line.py
```

And the setup.py is also pretty basic:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='chessil_tourney_inserter',
    .
    .
    .
    packages=['chessil_tourney_inserter'],
    zip_safe=False,

    install_requires = [
       'selenium'
    ],

    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
        'insertchessiltourney = chessil_tourney_inserter.command_line:main']
    })
```

As of right now `command_line.main` simply calls `chessil_tourney_inserter`:

```
import chessil_tourney_inserter.chessil_tourney_inserter as cti
import sys

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print("Usage: chessil_tourney_inserter.py *tournament name*")
        exit()
    cti.main();

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and chessil_tourney_inserter gives me an import error on:

```
import swiss98_text_parser
```

but if I try to run `chessil_tourney_inserter.py` directly it works, and if I add the package name to the import it would break `chessil_tourney_inserter.py`

So how am I supposed to set up the files so that imports will work correctly both when I run the file directly myself, and when I try to import it as a package or run it as a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `__init__.py` at the top folder too.

```
chessil_tourney_inserter/
setup.py
__init__.py
chessil_tourney_inserter/
    __init__.py (empty)
    chessil_tourney_inserter.py
    swiss98_text_parser.py
    command_line.py
```

See [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) for more information.

Comment: So simple and works perfectly. Thank you! I read on the __init__.py, but didn't realize it should be outside the directory... On my searches I found somewhere that starting from python 3 if the package name matches a directory it would search inside it even without the __init__.py file, is that the reason the code worked with the package name even without it?

Comment: Yes, I think so. [Pep 420](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages) introduced this change. Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.4.2 currently

Comment: `__init__.py ` is not need for namespace packages. `Namespace` packages are those which only contain other packages. Basically, they contain folders, but not files. You have two packages with the same name. You wanted the top level folder `chessil_tourney_inserter` to also be a package. Since it has a file `setup.py`, it is a `regular` package and hence needs an `__init__.py` Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30324656/817277 TL;DR `__init__.py` not required for `namespace` packages, but required for `regular` packages