# AttributeError when packaging python library

Tags: python-3.x, packaging

I'm in the process of learning how to package a python library using the [official guide](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#). I've started cloning the minimal sample package suggested in the guide [here](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject). I've then added the file my_module.py inside the folder sampleproject storing a simple power function. Another function is also stored in `/sampleproject/sampleproject/__init__.py`. The resulting structure of the library is the following

[image]

Finally, I've used pip to successfully install the package in the interpreter. The only thing left is to make sure that I'm able to run the functions stored in the subfolder sampleproject.

```
import sampleproject
sampleproject.main()

# Output
"Call your main application code here"
```

This is great. The package is able to run the function in `__init__.py`. However, the package is not able to find module.py:

```
import sampleproject
sampleproject.module

# Output
AttributeError: module 'sampleproject' has no attribute 'module'
```

I've tried to add `__init__.py` in the main folder and to change the settings in entry_points in setup.py without success. What should I let sampleproject to be able to find the function in module.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sampleproject.module` is a function you would like to execute?

In this case, do as for the sampleproject, add () to execute it:
`sampleproject.module()`

Otherwise, you can import your package like this:

```
import sampleproject.module
```

or:

```
from sampleproject import module
```

To be clearer, you would have to `import module` in your sampleproject `__init__.py`. Then, when you want to use the package, import it (is some py file at root):

```
import sampleproject  # is enough as it's going to import everything you stated in __init__.py
```

After that, you can start to use what's in the package you imported with maybe `module()` if you have a function called module in your package.

[**init**.py discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323607/why-do-i-have-to-add-a-blank-init-py-file-to-import-from-subdirectories)

Comment: Your solution work. However, I often read that it could be considered good practice to let __init__.py blank. How do people let users import their modules while keeping __init__.py blank? Does it involve changing the settings in setup.py?

Comment: It's good practice to have comprehensible code too in python. Leaving `__init__.py` blank would require more knowledge of the lib for the user (he has to know about module). It can be fine to leave it blank when making a collection of standalone functions which are not linked together, thus importing only required files (even if there's another way to do that from one huge file: `from lib import fcn1, fcn2...`). Anyways, if you have some init to perform (at module level) like multiple imports, you can do it in `__init__.py` (take a look at the std library in your python install folder for ex).

Answer (score 0):

it seems,

you are in sampleproject->module.py

so you need to try,

```
from sampleproject import module
```