# NameError while calling the parent class method from another module

Tags: python, inheritance, import

Here, I have created two python modules named as test1.py and test2.py.

In test1.py:

```
class c1: 
    pass

class c2:
    def e(self):
        return c3.x
```

In test2.py:

```
from test1 import *

class c3(c1):
    x = 1
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

class c4(c2):
    def __init__(self,y):
        self.y = y
```

Now, I need to call these modules using python 3.x interpreter:

```
$ python
>>> import test2 as t2
>>> import test1 as t1
>>> a = t2.c4(2)
>>> b = t2.c3(4)
>>> a.e()
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line1, in <module>
   File "~/test.py", line 6, in e return c3.x
NameError: name 'c3' is not defined
```

**Is there is any way to solve this problem?**

**Note:**
If I put those in a single module test.py:

```
class c1:
    pass

class c2:
    def e(self):
        return c3.x

class c3(c1):
    x = 1
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

class c4(c2):
     def __init__(self,y):
         self.y = y
```

If I run it in the interpreter:

```
$ python
>>> from test import *
>>> a = c4(2)
>>> b = c3(4)
>>> a.e()
1
```

**Solution:** *Yeah! Finally, this worked for me too.*

I did like this:

In test1.py:

```
import test2

class c1:
    pass

class c2:
    def e(self):
        return test2.c3.x
```

In test2.py:

```
from test1 import *

class c3(c1):
    x=1
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

class c4(c2):
     def __init__(self,y):
          self.y = y
```

If I run it in Python 3.x interpreter. I need to do this:

```
$ python
>>> from test2 import *
>>> from test1 import *
>>> a = c4(2)
>>> b = c3(4)
>>> a.e()
1
```

**Warning:** Do not do this:

```
$ python
>>> from test1 import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
NameError: name 'c1' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you just define `e` in `c3` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test1` doesn't know what `c3` is.So, you have to import `test2` in `test1`.
This can introduce **circular dependency** in your code.You can read more about circular dependency in python from below links:

[Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)

[Circular dependency in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894864/circular-dependency-in-python)

https://gist.github.com/datagrok/40bf84d5870c41a77dc6

[https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-**init**-method-in-python-class/](https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-__init__-method-in-python-class/)

This is working for me.

`import test2
class c1:
    pass
class c2:
    def e(self):
        a=test2.c3(4)
        print a.temp`

`import test1
class c3(test1.c1):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.temp=x
class c4(test1.c2):
    def __init__(self,y):
        self.y = y`

Comment: Also, you may want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30323607/why-do-i-have-to-add-a-blank-init-py-file-to-import-from-subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

Class `c2` does not know what `c3` is, because it is in another .py file.
So, you may need to import `test2` in `test1`. This results in circular imports - `test1` importing `test2` and `test2` importing `test1`.

To **fix circular imports**, either refactor your program to avoid circular imports or move the imports to the end of the module (like the second way you've done).